# Not get multiple place using Google Place API

Tags: swift, google-places-api

I use google place api and it working fine for single type place.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.0319597194644,72.5616482580887&radius=10000&type=atm&key=API_KEY
```

But, When set multiple place type at that time getting error. I use Alamofire class.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.0319597194644,72.5616482580887&radius=10000&type=atm|cafe&key=API_KEY
```

Code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.032166019274,72.5615383539303&radius=10000&type=atm|hospital&key=API_KEY", method: .get, parameters: NSDictionary(), encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
 print(response)
}
```

Error:
FAILURE: invalidURL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.032166019274,72.5615383539303&radius=10000&type=atm|hospital&key=API_KEY")

Comment: have you tried to change `|` with `%7C`?
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.032166019274,72.5615383539303&radius=10000&type=atm%7Chospital&key=AIzaSyCRoPDhBx3t-W7elRRGrlQt8byNZZaOYsg

Comment: @ocanal Thanks for supporting. That is working fine.